# Firebase Cloud Functions shell : add authentication token in order to call callable

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

How is it possible in firebase cloud function shell, to add authentication token, in order to test callables that require authentication ?

what is good syntax for user authentication token :

```
firebase > myAwsomeCallable({foo:"bar"},{"whatIsKeyforToken:"token");
```

Does anyone can knows a working example ? what is correct data structure for second parameter  (which is context/authent in callable signature) ?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for locally testing callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#invoke_https_callable_functions) currently says:

> Emulation of context.auth is currently unavailable.

So, what you're trying to do is currently not possible.  If this is important to you, please [file a feature request](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features).